# Get & diplay from database error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, stream

I am trying to write a simple stream, streaming everything from a mysql field. But my current script shows absolutely nothing.. no errors, nothing. Here it is:

```
include("user_sytem_scripts/connect.php");

   $sql_updates = mysql_query("SELECT item_id, username, item_content, update_time FROM updates ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 30")  or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_updates)){

    $update_id = $row["item_id"];
    $update_username = $row["username"];
    $item_content = $row["item_content"];
    $update_time = $row["update_time"];

$updatestream = '
   <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
                    <span class="liteGreyColor textsize9">' . $update_time . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $update_username . '"><strong>' . $username . '</strong></a> via <em></em></span><br />
                     ' . $item_content . '
            </td>
            </tr></table>'; }
```

Then down in the HTML I use: `<?php echo $updatestream ?>`

But as i said i get absolutly nothing.. Can anyone spot any errors or general mistakes that would cause this? Thanks :D

Comment: If you have error logging on, the error will be in the error log of the web server.

Comment: Did you really use this title (*Is there a way to check the users screen resolution?*), or did something in the stackoverflow database get confused?

Comment: FYI, PHP has a core concept called a [stream](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php), and you aren't using them here.  Be careful, using the term incorrectly can be confusing later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the following:

1. Does the query run when you run it manually (in phpMyAdmin for example)?
2. Do you get any output at all? If not, it seems that your while look is getting 0 results from the DB.

You should also change: `$updatestream = '` to `$updatestream .=` so that you append text, in the current while loop you'll overwrite the last `$updatestream` value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize $updatestream,($updatestream = ""), before the while loop, then inside the loop you change it to $updatestream .= "the string". You might want to echo your result at the end, sometimes we forget the little stuff.

```
echo $updatestream;
```